# UIPageControlのドットのサイズを変更

Tags: swift, swift4

## UIPageControlのドットのサイズを変更したい

UIPageControlで選択中のドットのサイズを大きくしたいと思っています。
調べたところObjective-Cでは以下のような記事がありました
http://usecase.hatenablog.com/entry/20101111/1332902630

ですが、Swiftでの文献が見当たりません。

以下の画像のようなUIPageControlを作りたいと思っています。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: はじめまして。`Objective-C`で書かれたソースを`Swift`に書き替えたいという質問でしょうか？でしたら、[Appleのサンプルコードを参考にするにはObjective-Cの理解が必要ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43579)の拙回答が多少なりお役に立てると思います。その上で、この部分がどう書き替えて良いかわからない点がありましたらその部分に焦点を絞り、質問を更新して下されば回答を得やすくなると思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

初めまして、マレーシア人だから日本語はあんまり上手じゃないんだ。
実はObjective-Cで書かれたソースは、Swiftに転換がとても簡単だよ。

これ君は言及した記事の中にいるソースSwiftのバージョンです：

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        for i in 0 ..< numberOfPages {
            if let pageIcon = subviews[i] as? UIImageView, i == 0 {
                if i == currentPage {
                    pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: "PageIcon_Active.png")
                    pageIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                } else {
                    pageIcon.image = UIImage(named: "PageIcon.png")
                    pageIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

お役に立てばよかったです。